Problems in the API call passing objects
I'm making a post and I'm passing an object called Employee.
This Employee object has a field idSituation, which is a foreign key to another object Situation.
When I try to make a call via post to the Login API passing the Employee type, it gives a message that says

Situation object field is required.

I wanted to pass only the Employee object and within this object the Situation type field to be null. Since I'm not going to pass this data in the JSON.
Here are

the codes for the Employee and Situation objects

Post API with the JSON sent

Returns


   public class Funcionario 
   {

       [Key]
       public Int64 idFuncionario { get; set; }

       public string descricaoFuncionario { get; set; } 

       public int idSituacao { get; set; } 
       [ForeignKey("idSituacao")]
       public virtual Situacao Situacao { get; set; } 

   }


    public class Situacao
    {
        [Key]
        public int idSituacao { get; set; } 

        public string descricaoSituacao { get; set; } 
    }


    [HttpPost("Login")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login(Funcionario param)
    {}


https://localhost:7296/api/account/login
{
    "descricaofuncionario":"master",
    "senha":"A95135782aZ!"
}


{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "errors": {
        "Situacao": [
            "The Situacao field is required."
        ]
    },
    "traceId": "00-2314d7f68cc1c6dadba6f08f899167a8-bd41adabd04d52fd-00"
}



{
    "descricaofuncionario":"master",
    "senha":"A95135782aZ!",
     "situacao":{"idsituacao":13,"descricaosituacao":"ativo"}
}

If you pass it with situation data, it works.
I have another project that allows sending objects employee with null status.

Instead of posting the data with the entity type, we recommend working with Data Transfer Object. Data Transfer Object aims to provide a model template for transferring data between the view (front-end) and controller (back-end) with the data/property that is only required.
public class LoginModel 
{
   public string DescricaoFuncionario { get; set; } 

   public string Senha { get; set; } 

    // Other properties
}

Next, you need to implement casting from LoginModel to Funcionario with implicit/explicit operator. Note that create a partial class with the same name and namespace as Funcionario.
public partial class Funcionario 
{
    public static implicit operator Funcionario(LoginModel model)
    {
        return new Funcionario
        {
            descricaoFuncionario = model.DescricaoFuncionario
            // Mapping for Other properties
        };
    }
}

Use the LoginModel as your request body type in your controller action and cast the param to the Funcionario instance if required.
[HttpPost("Login")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Login(LoginModel param)
{
    Funcionario funcionario = param;

    ...
}

Alternatively, you may look for AutoMapper library to perform the type casting.

I suggest you use a Data Transfer Object (DTO). As taken from Microsoft docs:
A DTO is an object that defines how the data will be sent over the network.

It will abstract away all of the relational stuff and masks your database structure.
Something like this:
 public class FuncionarioDto
 {

    public string descricaoFuncionario { get; set; } 

    public int idSituacao { get; set; } 

 }

And your endpoint will look like:
[HttpPost("Login")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Login(FuncionarioDto param)
{}


I've used separate DTOs for both the request and response types. So for example, if you need to return a Functionario object with the id (and no Situation data) then you can create a separate FuncitonarioResponseDto. Like this:
public class FuncitonarioResponseDto
 {
    public Int64 idFuncionario { get; set; }

    public string descricaoFuncionario { get; set; } 

    public int idSituacao { get; set; } 

 }

And if your POST response returns something it could look like this:
[HttpPost("Login")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ResponseType(typeof(FuncitonarioResponseDto))]
public IActionResult Login(FuncionarioDto param)
{
   return Ok(new FuncitonarioResponseDto(){
      idFuncionario = 1, // or whatever id gets assigned
      descricaoFuncionario = param.descricaoFuncionario,
      idSituacao = param.idSituacao
   });
}



Maybe it's not the best option, but to solve it for now I set the fields in the class as not mandatory and it's solved.
public String? cep { get; set; }
public String? logr { get; set; }

